# How to merge the video display QGraphicsScene with the rest of the code which uses QQuickWindow?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

So, I have a Qt code with text boxes and buttons using `QQuickWindow`, and then a video stream using `QGraphicsScene`.

I intend to show them in one window. How to go ahead?

This is what I have tried (there isn't any video in use currently, but I expect it to display "hello world" from qml file):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml/QQmlContext>
#include <QtQml/QQmlEngine>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QStringLiteral("qml/untitled/main.qml"));

    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(&view);

    QWidget *p = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
    layout->addWidget(p);
    p->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The QML file contains:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360


    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```